# How to get the BalloonHint size?

Tags: c++builder, vcl, c++builder-xe, balloon-tip

I need to position a `TBalloonHint` at the lower left corner, just above the taskbar.
To be able to calculate the position I need to know the Height and Width of the BalloonHint window.

I can't find any functions or properties that will tell me this and what I understand, a BalloonHint resize itself depending on the content. So I can't calculate with a fixed height and width either.

Well, the only one I found was `SetHintSize()`, but it needs a `TCustomHintWindow` and I have no clue of how to set it up properly.

Can someone please show me an example of how to either create a custom hint or get the size of the TBalloonHint.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @kokbira no, I'm officially still looking for a solution, but I have not touch that project for a while now.